# C# Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() does not return resource names

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(). I want to browse through my application's resources and here is what I'm doing:

```
    foreach (string res in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
```

My application has several image resources, and I expected the above code to list their names. Instead, all I get is this output:

- G19SysMon.frmMain.resources
- G19SysMon.frmSetup.resources
- G19SysMon.Properties.Resources.resources

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Are your image resources configured with "embedded resource" as the build action?

Comment: No, they are linked at compile time. Changing this setting to "embedded in .resx" doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My application has several image resources

It does, but they are stored in a .resx file.  Like frmMain.resx.  That file gets translated to a "blob", a single chunk of binary data.  Produced by Resgen.exe, it has the `.resources` filename extension.  And *that* blob was added as a manifest resource.  You see the .resources blobs with your code.

Finding the original resource back in the blob is the job of the ResourceReader class.  You could use it in a for-each loop to enumerate the original resources.  But you typically use the ResourceManager class, an extra layer above ResourceReader.  It support localization, reading resources from satellite files.  Winforms uses ComponentResourceManager, a derived class, and automatically calls ApplyResources().  You can see this back in the InitializeComponent() method.

Answer (score 0):

Open the assembly dll wiht ildasm (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will show you the resource names in the manifest. If you are trying to get different names then GetManifestResourceNames() is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

@HansPassant: Thanks for your perfect reply.

This code:

```
    ResourceSet resSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, false, true);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resSet)
    {
        if (entry.Value is Image))
        {
            // Use the image
        }
    }
```

does exactly what I need.